# Where to find source code of ActionController::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, controller

I am checking the structure of the initial steps of a tutorial, to build a blog and while going through the code block by block, got to the point in which I want to read the code of ActionController::Base, but I am not able to find it, maybe some help?

Thank you.

Comment: The `ActionController::Base` is the base class from which `ApplicationController` and therefore your controllers inherit. It's part of the core API, if you want to have a look at it you can do-so in your IDE

Answer (score 2):

[Here it is](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb). You won't find much there, though. `Base` module is quite thin. It consists almost entirely out of list of modules to `include`.

Answer (score 1):

you can read the Rails Source Code

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb

or the API docs

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base

Comment: Thank you for the answer, will be checking both documentation files.